# Route Error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am setting up my own admin for a Laravel project and everything is going along fine until I hit what seems to be a routing issue.  Here's my situation so far.

Within my views folder I have a folder named panel which holds all of my views for the admin panel.  This is working perfectly.  I have full access to the panel without a problem.  Within the panel directory I have a folder named users which holds my views for the UsersControllers.  This is where I'm struggling.  My route for those views is as follows:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Route:list shows those routes as users.index, users.store etc.

In the top nav bar of the panel I have a link to the users index as

```
<li><a href="{{ url('/users.index') }}">Users</a></li>
```

I've also tried using

```
<li><a href="{{ url('users.index') }}">Users</a></li>
```

Either way, this should be calling the index() method of the UsersController.  That method looks like this

```
public function index()
{
    return view('panel.users.index');
}
```

I've also tried just

```
public function index()
{
    return view('users.index');
}
```

No matter what I try I get

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

I would really appreciate a bit of wisdom on how to resolve this one.

Comment: Instead of `{{ url('users.index') }}` it should be `{{ route('users.index') }}`

Comment: you can try `php artisan route:list` in your console. Also maybe check https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers -> **Actions Handled By Resource Controller** for clear examples on how the routes work (look at "Route Name" column). Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this for index

```
<li><a href="{{ url('users') }}">Users</a></li>
```

or you can use action

```
<li><a href="{{ action('UsersController@index') }}">Users</a></li>
```

Comment: That's outstanding.  Thank you.  As I sit here looking at it I'm guessing it's because the ".index" is implied in the get() function of the resource route, so calling it was essentially calling it twice?

Comment: I prefer the first one. Because it hides the structure of the route for the Blade view.